# Exclude lines based in multiple strings in R

Tags: r, matrix, lines

I want to exclude all lines in Matrix **Y** where cells in `numberall` column is equal to `number1` or `number2` column in Matrix **X**.

Matrix **X**:

```
  number1  number2  inf
   gen1     genx1   223
   gen1     genx2   221
   gen2     genx3   224
   gen2     genx5   225
```

Matrix **Y**:

```
   numberall  inf
    gen1      223
    genx1     256
    gen2      225
    genx2     214
    gen3      563
    genx3     235
    gen4      256
    genx4     568
```

Output:

```
   numberall  inf
    gen3      563
    gen4      256
    genx4     568
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic, instead of wait for us to decipher it?

Comment: I wanna to exclude all lines in matrix Y where cells in "numberall" collumn is equal to number1 or number2 collumn in matrix X.

Comment: OK, I edited your question to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = read.table(header=T, text="
number1  number2  inf
gen1     genx1   223
gen1     genx2   221
gen2     genx3   224
gen2     genx5   225
")

y = read.table(header=T, text="
numberall  inf
gen1      223
genx1     256
gen2      225
genx2     214
gen3      563
genx3     235
gen4      256
genx4     568
")

rows = y$numberall %in% x$number1 | y$numberall %in% x$number2
y[!rows,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Y` and `X` are actually data frames:

```
Y[!(Y$numberall %in% as.character(unlist(X[, 1:2]))), ]
```

produces:

```
#   numberall inf
# 5      gen3 563
# 7      gen4 256
# 8     genx4 568
```